# Is it possible to use Fluent Assertions library with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, fluent-assertions

[Fluent Assertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/) is a .NET library for assertions of any kind, but I cannot get it to work with PowerShell. Is it possible at all?

I used **Add-Type** cmdlet to add the library's DLLs and tried the following example:

```
PS C:\Users\ymm> $test = 'test string'
PS C:\Users\ymm> $test.[FluentAssertions.AssertionExtensions]::Should().BeNull()
```

But got the following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Should" and the argument count: "0".
At line:1 char:1
+ $test.[FluentAssertions.AssertionExtensions]::Should().BeNull()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at Pester (https://github.com/pester/Pester)? It's written for Powershell testing and so doesn't have the verbosity of a native .NET library.

Comment: Pester is good, but does not compare to this library. And as far as I rememeber,it requires certain file structure and syntax to work, i.e. I cannot just use an assertion itself without Describe block etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to call it as an explicit static method.

In theory, this would be:

```
[FluentAssertions.AssertionExtensions]::Should($test).BeNull()
```

However, while this is a simple example, you may have to explitly type the arguments to avoid ambiguity later. Powershell will most likely implicitly make the arguments `PSObject` which gets resolved to `Object` instead of `string` or any other concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

`Should`, as well as all of the assertions in Fluent assertions, are extension methods which are not supported by PowerShell.

I'd recommend using a PowerShell specific assertion library, or else a .net library with regular methods for syntax.

In addition to the extension methods, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241985/calling-generic-static-method-in-powershell) for what's involved in in coming generic methods on non-generic classes.